# role.setColor is not a function on discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently trying to make a bot that changes role color with discord.js

I found there is a 'role.setColor' function on documentation, but I haven't find any examples on that.

I want to make it when i write ':renk' to the chat, but it doesn't work at all.

Code:

```
if(message.content == ':renk')
{
    const role = '359005310536646681'
    role.setColor('#FFFFFF');       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your role object is of type String. `'359005310536646681'` is the string representation of the snowflake (ID) of your role. And the String object doesn't have a setColor() function. You want to get the role that has this id.

The Guild object has a roles collection. You can then search for your role inside that collection.

You can find the Guild by searching the guilds collection on your bots client, or from the message object.

Comment: var role = message.guild.id;
role.setColor('#FFFFFF');      Is this the true one? I get the guild id with messaging but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
if(message.content == ':renk')
{
    const role = message.guild.roles.get('359005310536646681')
    role.setColor('#FFFFFF');       
}
```